# Ambiguous reference to member Swift 3

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, swift2, swift3

I am migrating my project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3. And having difficulty as expected.

Here is a function which is being used for OAuth, using [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift). I have tried to convert

```
class func OAuthSwiftAuthorization(inViewController viewController: UIViewController, withOAuthInfo info:FitnessTracker, successHandler:@escaping MyOAuthNewSuccessHandler, failure: @escaping ((_ error: NSError) -> Void)) {

    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    info.consumerKey,
        consumerSecret: info.consumerSecret,
        authorizeUrl:   info.authorizeUrl,
        accessTokenUrl: info.accessTokenUrl,
        responseType:   info.responseType
    )

    oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = SafariURLHandler(viewController: viewController, oauthSwift: oauthswift)
    oauthswift.accessTokenBasicAuthentification = true
    oauthswift.allowMissingStateCheck = true

    oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: URL(string: info.callBackUrl)!, scope: info.scope, state: info.state, success: { (credential, response, parameters) in

             successHandler(credential, response, parameters)
    }) { (error) in

        failure(error: error)
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error at

```
oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: URL(string: info.callBackUrl)!, scope: info.scope, state: info.state, success: { (credential, response, parameters) in
```

Error states

> Ambiguous reference to member 'authorize(withCallbackURL:scope:state:parameters:headers:success:failure:)'

Here is the working code from Swift 2.

```
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(
        URL(string: info.callBackUrl)!,
        scope: info.scope, state:info.state,
        success: { credential, response, parameters in

            successHandler(credientials: credential, response: response, params: parameters)
        },
        failure: { error in

            failure(error: error)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    )
```

**UPDATE:**

Error does not appear unitil I type success and faliure handelrs. This complies fine:

```
        oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: URL(string: info.callBackUrl)!, scope: info.scope, state: info.state, success: { (credential, response, parameters) in
        // successHandler(credential, response, parameters)
    }) { (erorr) in
        // failure(error: error
    }
```

So Please guide me Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by some shortcomings of Swift's type inference in combination with closures.
You could try one of the following:

Either don't use trailing closures, e.g.

```
oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: URL(string: info.callBackUrl)!, scope: info.scope, state: info.state, success: { (credential, response, parameters) in

         successHandler(credential, response, parameters)
}, failure: { (error) in

    failure(error: error)
    print(error.localizedDescription)
})
```

or provide an explicit type for error, e.g.

```
 oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: URL(string: info.callBackUrl)!, scope: info.scope, state: info.state, success: { (credential, response, parameters) in

         successHandler(credential, response, parameters)
 }) { (error: Error) in

     failure(error: error)
     print(error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

Comment: Not using a trailing closure did the trick. But I do not understand why !!

Comment: It's a shortcoming, see here:
https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-dev/Week-of-Mon-20160704/002370.html

Answer (score 1):

For reference:
This kind of error appears when there's more than one variable/method with the same name, does your `oauthswift` has more than one "thing" called "authorize"? like another method? 
My error was that i declared:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
```

and in

```
let _ = try localFileManager.createDirectory(...)
```

I got the same error, changing the variable name in `localFileManager` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error **Ambiguous reference to member** with the same method on converting it from **Swift 4 to Swift 5**. Looks like the completion handler has been changed to support the new **Result** type. Changing the completing handler to below fixed the issue for me,

```
        oauthVarSwift.authorize( withCallbackURL: URL(string: "")!,
                             scope: "", state:"", completionHandler: {  result in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let credential, let response,  let parameters):
                                    print(credential.oauthToken)

                                case .failure(let error):
                                 print(error)
                                }

          })
```