# Swift - Ambiguous reference to member '==' error

Tags: swift

I've done some searching and can't seem to find a solution for my below issue. I'm fairly new to swift so working through some issues. I have the below function which is just a stub containing the signature of the function and a return value just to get it to compile.

The test code is what I've been given, I did not write this and unfortunately cannot alter it.

My issues is that when I run it, it says that the test that calls this function has an "Ambiguous call to member '=='". I cannot alter the test code. Whatever the issue is must be in my function signature i'm assuming but could use some help.

**Function That I am writing (That I assume contains the issue):**

```
func contains(target: StringOrInt, compare: Character ) -> Bool {                                                                                                
    return false                                                                                                       
} // contains
```

**Test that calls the function (I'm not allowed to edit this and did not write it):**

```
func test_contains_cons_2_strings_3() {
let list1 = MyList.cons("foo", MyList.cons("bar", MyList.empty))
assertEquals(testName: "test_contains_cons_2_strings_3",
         expected: true,
         received: list1.contains(target: "bar", compare: ==))//Error is on this line '=='
} // test_contains_cons_2_strings_3
```

**Error:**
*main.swift:807:67: error: ambiguous reference to member '=='
                 received: list1.contains(target: "foo", compare: ==))*

Also note that "StringOrInt" is a protocol that I've defined that acts as an extension on both Int and String. This is done because the test code (Which i did not write and cannot edit) passes both strings and ints to this same variable and function.

Thanks advance for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous reference to member Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952036/ambiguous-reference-to-member-swift-3)

Comment: What's the definition of `StringOrInt`?

Comment: It's clear you're from a Haskell background, or something like it, but just so you know, pretty much none of this is "conventional Swift", as would be written or recognized by the majority of the community. Swift prefers `lowerCamelCase` for functions, not `snake_case`. It prefers writing instance functions on types, rather than taking `target` parameters. It prefers arrays over linked lists (like `cons`, which perform terribly in comparison).

Comment: Why are you passing `==` instead of a single Character `"="` ?

Comment: I've updated the code to mention this, StringOrInt is a protocol that allows for both type int and string to be passed into that variable because the test code passes both of these types into the same variable at different points.

Comment: The test code is what I've been given to write a function for to get the test to pass. I did not write the test code only the function that it calls and unfortunately cannot change it

Comment: @Alexander This looks like the kind of code you get handed these days for coding challenges (usually as part of an interview). They're generally developed in JavaScript and then transliterated into other languages. The Swift is always horrible, and forces you to write things to pass the tests that you should never write in proper Swift.

Comment: Also, we would need to see the definition and implementation details (particularly how you've implemented `==`) for `StringOrInt`. You suggest here that `contains` is a top-level function, but its being called as a method. It's unclear how this code is actually structured.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to compare two strings by passing "==" operator  and return a Boolean value.If so you can use the below method,

```
func myList(_ compare:((String, String) -> Bool)) -> Bool {
    return compare("foo","bar")
}

myList(==)
```

Comment: Yea I can definitely see that the test function is creating a list of strings, it is then checking if that list of strings has something "==" to the target it passes. One issue is that in the test code this contains function is called a lot and sometimes it compares Ints, sometimes Strings so i have to be able to deal with both. I'm going to try and apply your thought process above and see if I can make some progress. Thank you very much for your advice

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004623/have-a-variable-with-multiple-types-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using the below. I implemented an enum of generic type and the nan extension on that enum. I then used this generic type  within the contains function to represent multiple types instead of StringOrInt. Thanks everyone for the comments and the help.

enum implemented:

```
indirect enum my_list<A> {
   case cons(A, my_list<A>)
   case empty
}
```

I then implemented in extension for this enum "extension my_list" and placed the contains function within the extension.

contains function signature/stub:

```
func contains(target: A, compare:((A, A) -> Bool))     
-> Bool {
   return true
}// contains
```